# Why does my WriteableBitmap not display on my Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

Note: this was fixed by updating the drivers, as noted in the duplicate.

In my real WPF (.NET 6) application, I have an `Image` that I want to use to display a camera feed. I receive 30fps and I want to render those frames as efficiently as possible.

I had *expected* to be able to create a single `WriteableBitmap` and a single `Image`, set the bitmap as the source for the image, then call `WriteableBitmap.WritePixels` for each frame. I'm already dispatching to the UI thread, so there should be no threading issues there.

In reality, this creates a very jerky image - at least on my development laptops. (Weirdly, it doesn't appear to be a problem on the desktop I use for "production" with this application. The desktop is significantly more powerful than the laptops, if that's relevant.) If I create a new `WriteableBitmap` on each frame, the problem goes away - but that's very inefficient. (If I'm going to create a new source on each frame, I can just use `BitmapSource.Create`.)

I've reproduced the problem in the sample code below. The intention is that every time you click the "Generate" button, it replaces the content of the image with random bytes (white noise with colours, effectively). In reality, with the code as shown, the "noise" is never generated *on one laptop*. On the other laptop (where the real app is still jerky) the demo app works fine. I'm baffled.

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Demo;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WriteableBitmap bitmap;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // If this code is moved into DrawImage, it's fine
        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(128, 128, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }

    private void DrawImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new byte[128 * 128 * 4];
        var random = new Random();
        random.NextBytes(data);
        bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 128, 128), data, 128 * 4, 0);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="200" Width="150">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Width="128" Height="128" x:Name="image" />
        <Button Margin="5" Click="DrawImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Generate</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As noted in the comment, if you move the lines in the constructor to the `DrawImage` method (creating a new `WriteableBitmap` for each button click) it works fine.

Some variations on this:

- If you move just `image.Source` into `DrawImage`, then the *first* image is generated correctly, but after that it doesn't work
- If you make the method asynchronous add a `Task.Delay` call, then if the `Task.Delay` is *before* the place where `image.Source` is set, it's fine, but if the `Task.Delay` comes between the `image.Source` assignment and the `WritePixels` call, the image isn't shown.

I've also tried using explicit `Lock` and `Unlock` calls (with `AddDirtyRect`) - it doesn't help.

The [example code in the `WriteableBitmap` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) behaves similarly: the first pixel to be drawn "works", but that's the only one.

I've tried this in .NET 4.8 as well, but that fails too.

This *looks* to be pretty simple code - what am I missing? (I'm sure I'll kick myself...)

Comment: The code is ok, and it works fine in a .NET 6 WPF application on my development laptop.

Comment: It works for me as well (on a desktop PC). Not sure, could this perhaps be some strange issue with some GPU driver? For what's worth, i am using a Nvidia GTX 1070 Ti.

Comment: Is the overall plan a good one? I've never tried to translate a camera feed like this. I wonder about using a new bitmap per frame, freezing and multi threading rather than dispatching. No idea how good an idea that is though.

Comment: @Clemens: Bizarrely, it works fine on my other laptop too. It's very odd.

Comment: @Andy: I'm already dispatching once per frame for various other aspects. (And I only know whether I need to render it at all once I'm on the dispatcher thread.) The code's been working fine for a while - it's absolutely fine on the desktop machine. And weirdly, it works on my other laptop as well. It's all highly confusing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283077/writeablebitmap-writepixels-not-refreshing-on-some-pcs

Comment: @Andy: You star, thanks! Will try that update now...

Comment: @JonSkeet, From my personal experience with cameras, I think it's better to use asynchronous frame creation:
- The event is processed in the Task on the thread pool;
- A frame is received in the Task;
- The frame is converted to a derivative of ImageSource;
- ImageSource is frozen;
- After freezing, it is assigned to the property to which the Image.Source property is bind.

Comment: @EldHasp: As noted earlier, I don't actually know whether or not I need to render the frame until I'm on the dispatcher thread. (There are three cameras; it's unusual for more than one to be active at a time.) But I may give that a try when I have time.